# Android app fragment ----use button to trigger another switch button

Tags: java, android

I tried lots of times and wrote the following codes. I want to click the button to trigger the switch button at the same time in the fragment. And the text will be changed. But when I ran the code, the app would be crashed. Plz help me to solve this problem. tks!  BTW I use the fragment to implement into the activity.

---

---

fragment_scan.java

```
  public class ScanFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER


    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters

    private Button buttonSCAN;
    boolean is_enable = true;
    private  Switch SwitchScan;
    Switch sw;

    public ScanFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ScanFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ScanFragment fragment = new ScanFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);
        buttonSCAN = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSCAN);
        SwitchScan=(Switch) rootView.findViewById(R.id.switch_Below);
        buttonSCAN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            boolean on=((Switch)rootView).isChecked();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(is_enable == true)
                {
                    is_enable = false;
                    buttonSCAN.setText("Turn on SCAN");
                    boolean on=true;
                    if(on){

                    }
                }
                else{
                    is_enable = true;
                    buttonSCAN.setText("Turn off SCAN");
                    boolean on=false;
                    if(!on){

                    }

                }
        sw.setEnabled(is_enable);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }



    public void switchclick(View view){

    }
```

fragment_scan.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ScanFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch_Below"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:showText="true"
        android:textOff="   Scan on   "
        android:textOn="   Scan off   "
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSCAN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="Turn on SCAN " />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When you post a question to try to get help with a crash, posting the crash error and callstack is usually a good idea for people to see what the error is and where it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things wrong with your code:

- `boolean on = ((Switch)rootView).isChecked();` you cannot cast `rootView` to `Switch`, change this to `boolean on = SwitchScan.isChecked();`
- `sw.setEnabled(is_enable);` `sw` is never initialized and calling any method to this will cause NullPointerException, I think you should change that to your correct switch which is `SwitchScan` so please change it to  `SwitchScan.setEnabled(is_enable);` ideally it should not be `setEnabled` but `setChecked`

These changes will fix your crashes.